# Checkout svn directory without client software?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout, websvn, svn-client, gforge

The computers where I work are locked down very tight, I have one computer I can connect to the internet with, but only Internet Explorer and Outlook can access the internet. I also cannot install software on it. I have a separate "standalone" computer which I can install or run anything I want on, but I cannot connect it to the internet.

I need to download a directory from a gforge svn. Is there a way to do this from my browser? I imagine a website where I can enter the address of the directory I need to checkout, and it produces a zip file I can download in Internet Explorer that contains that directory and all of its subdirectories. I need to download the code on my internet connected computer, and transfer it to my "standalone" computer to run it.

I've searched around a bunch and many people have similar problem but don't have the same restrictions as me. For example many people can use [DownloadSVN](http://downloadsvn.codeplex.com/) because it is a portable program that doesn't need to install anything on your computer. However, in my case the DownloadSVN executable is not allowed to access the internet.

Most github projects, and some gforge projects have an option to "download zip" of the current directory, that is great, however the gforge svn I need to download does not have this option. I could go through and manually download each individual file, but this would take many hours.

Not sure if it matters but I'm on windows 7 with internet explorer 10. The key information is I cannot access the internet from any software I install on my computer, so any kind of client software that runs outside of IE will not work (maybe something that can run within IE like some kind of javascript would work though?).

Comment: Don't you have the IDE's even? Like, say, eclipse? If not, I wonder of what use will that checked code be to you. Most SVN project maintainers host their content on the web that can be viewed on the browser. That could save you a checkout, if that's all you need. Also see if [this](https://github.com/sara-nl/js-webdav-client) js library can be of any help to you.

Comment: Oh good question. I need to download the code and put it on a separate computer that I can install anything on, but does not have internet access to run it. I'll update the question.

Comment: I usually go with `wget` for such needs, but I honestly haven't tried that to checkout an svn project. You can give it a try: `wget -m -np http://host/svn/project/trunk`, though.

Comment: I went ahead and tried wget to be through, but it is not able to access the internet: "Unable to establish SSL connection". The wget executable is not allowed past my firewall, only internet explorer and outlook are.

Comment: Hmm, the `curl` doesn't return the webpage contents either? I mean `curl [url]` fails due to a similar reason? There used to be a site for this, but I don't recall the name. I can't try it even being at work, but it goes something like: `svndownload.eu5.org`.

Comment: Correct, curl is not installed, if I did install it, I think would do the same. http://svndownload.eu5.org/ did use to provide this function but that url does not exist anymore. Not sure what happen.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of with that draconian of a restriction is to write a script that automates IE, "navigates" with it to the web view of the source repository, and downloads each linked file (including recreating the directory structure).

Starter:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application" 
$ie.navigate("URL_TO_GFORGE")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep 1} 
$ie.visible = $true 
$doc = $ie.Document
```

See for more (I copied the code from here) at [IE Automation with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942884/ie-automation-with-powershell)

Then you'd have to walk through the DOM of the web page that's loaded, locate each of the files, and download that way.

But every time there's a new release of the code you're "checking out", you'll have to do the whole thing all over.